# Machine Learning on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, optimization, machine-learning, bigdata, sparse-matrix

I am interested in running machine learning algorithms directly inside of PostgreSQL as described [here](https://asterixdb.ics.uci.edu/pub/ieee12.pdf).

The basic gist of the paper is that I write my algorithm as a function which gives the nth model

```
def get_model(n):
   return make_step(model(n-1))

def make_step(model):
   # Compute gradient and make update and return new model
```

The idea is that the database will optimize the data flow such that the query runs very quickly.

My data is about 10^12 samples, 10^9 features, with an average of 1000 features that aren't zero per sample (highly! sparse).

I justify my question because I found the following,

- [For defining sparse vectors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/xtypes.html)
- [Defining inner products](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html)
- [The recursive Query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html)
- And I am pretty sure that PostgreSQL can be distributed onto many machines

My questions are,

- How well will PostgreSQL handle sparse matrix vector products?
- Will PostgreSQL actually optimize for better data flow and processing?
- Are any of my assumptions or other goals not realistic?

Comment: PostgreSQL itself does not distribute across multiple/many machines. There are a number projects and forks which can do that: DTM, pg_shard, Postgres-XL, Greenplum ...

Comment: I don't fully understand your question: are you looking for help in writing a machine learning algorithm, or are you looking for help applying existing algorithm to your existing data? Both are complex problems on it's own, and you should pick your problems one by one, not try to solve all at once.

Comment: Have a look at MADlib, which comes with a number of existing algorithm, and supports PostgreSQL. http://madlib.net/

Comment: Thanks you. I am not looking for help applying machine learning algorithms. I can do this just fine. For a particular problem which I need to consistently retrain every day (for security purposes), I am researching ways to make this computation scale as our data set is growing quickly to sizes that make single machine computation unfeasible. I need to make this scale. Yes, I have looked into many, MANY other options (name it and I have probably tried it), but they don't scale well for our data due to the sparsity and other problems. Hence my questions.